Laravel using a CASE which supplies data from a Subquery
I've been tasked with adding a new specific column to a report (sourced from a MySQL database) with criteria that returns a new column value based on conditions. It seems like the ideal use for a CASE clause:
select *,
CASE
  WHEN check_out_time >= now() + INTERVAL 25 HOUR THEN "Requires Attention"
  WHEN (
    SELECT count(*)
    FROM shift_activities
    WHERE shift_id = `shifts`.`id`
  ) <= 0 THEN "Requires Attention"
  ELSE "Complete"
END AS "VisitStatus"
from `shifts` 
-- JOINs left off

The only downside is, one of these CASE/WHEN clauses requires a subquery, which doesn't really fit into Eloquent nicely. In this case, the Eloquent query is relatively simple:
$open_shifts = $client->shifts()
  ->with("customers", "activities")
  ->get();

Using the laravel-eloquent-case extension, its straightforward to add a CASE that's a simple comparison:
$open_shifts = $client->shifts()
  ->with('caregiver', 'activities')
  ->case(function (CaseBuilder $case) {
    $case->when('checked_out_time', '>=', 'INTERVAL 25 HOUR')->then('Requires Attention')
      ->else('Complete');
    }, 'VisitStatus')
  ->get();

But since I have one that relies on a count(*) of a joining table, it doesn't work that well. It causes persistent errors and I am not clear on how to best use that library here. What other options do I have to use this CASE/WHEN in Eloquent, or should I just use Raw SQL here?

Which dbms are you using?

The project is using MySQL 5.5

A quick read through the documentation for laravel-eloquent-case suggests you should use other methods.
INTERVAL 25 HOUR is a SQL expression so whenRaw should probably be used.
For the subquery, I think you can use the DB Facade's toSql/toRawSql methods to get a proper expression.
->case(
    function (CaseBuilder $case) {
        $sub = DB::query()
            ->selectRaw('count(*)')
            ->from('shift_activities')
            ->whereColumn('shift_id', 'shifts.id');

        $case
            ->whenRaw('checked_out_time >= INTERVAL 25 HOUR')->then('Requires Attention')
            ->whenRaw("({$sub->toSql()}) <= 0", $sub->getBindings())->then('Requires Attention') // although $sub->getBindings() could be ommited here since there are no bindings.
            ->else('Complete');
    },
    'VisitStatus'
)

Personally I've always used raw statements for CASE WHEN expressions.

I actually found myself running into a similar issue when using whenRaw so I ended up just adding a selectRaw to add these CASE calls, negating the need for the library.
